# Save data to file not working properly

Tags: android, save

I use the following code to save password in a txt file:

```
String  FILE_NAME="lol.txt";
public void writeData(String password){
            FileOutputStream fOut = null;
            OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
            try{
                fOut = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                osw.write(password);
                osw.close();
                fOut.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
```

but When I retrive the password that I just Saved using toast its appears OK, but when I Log it into my LogCat I got Something like the following:

```
gana???????????????????????????????????? .... and more four lines.
```

I save the word gana into my file using save method which work as OnClikc method that set value of EditText as password as below:

```
public void save(View v){
            password= txt.getText().toString();
            writeData(password);
     }
```

any Way or clue how can I solve this problem?

regards

Comment: `When I retrive the password that I just Saved using toast`... Please show this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to reading file

```
byte[] b = null;
    try 
    {
        //read file data...
        FileInputStream myFile = openFileInput("lol.txt");
        b = new byte[1024];
        myFile.read(b);
        Log.i("Pass", "File data is: " + new String(b).trim());   
        myFile.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    }
```

only difference with your code is that i am using `new String(b).trim()` to remove blank space.

Comment: thanks Srivastava i think the only thing that I needed is to use trim() method to remove the blank space for my code to work fine, really appreciated.